# NFS does not see underlying NTFS

Tags: server, mount, ntfs, nfs

I have an internet sharing server which is connected with a hdd with music I'd like to listen via wifi.

I have tried creating a samba or ftp share, but they are so slow (or I just do not know how to make them faster =) ).
So I have tried to share via NFS.

I have followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04, and I was able to connect, but when I go into a dir, to where my hdd is mounted, I can see nothing.

On server:

```
/srv/share ➜  ls -l 
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24576 Apr  2 16:15 hdd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abra abra     0 Apr 16 21:22 hello
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abra abra     0 Apr 16 21:19 hi
/srv/share ➜  ls hdd
...various dirs...
```

On client:

```
~/server ➜  ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 abra abra 4096 Apr 16 21:19 hdd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abra abra    0 Apr 16 21:22 hello
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abra abra    0 Apr 16 21:19 hi
~/server ➜  ls hdd
~/server ➜
```

Or maybe NTS is just an overkill and there is an easier way to share mounted hdd fast via wifi?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My /etc/exports

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/srv/share  192.168.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)
```

Comment: By default, Nfs exports don't include mounted directories. If you export a folder on the mounted hdd, it should work. I don't remember by heart, if there's also an option one can specify in exports to transgress filesystem boundaries. Maybe you should read the exports man page.

Comment: Please add the Solved bit as an answer, and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had to add

```
/srv/share/hdd  192.168.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)
```

in `/etc/exports` and it works.

There is an option `crossmount` to add in exports, but I didn't manage to get it work.